# Running Parallel Karate Tests with cucmber report from jar file

Tags: karate

I am trying to run karate from jar file. I am able to do so as per the below link

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/529

But i was using parallel execution and cucumber reports so far in my suite. But I am not able to achieve that when I run from the jar file. Is it possible to achieve that while running from Jar also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the `-T` option.

Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#parallel-execution

Also do check out the ZIP release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: thanks Peter for your quick reponse, I believe in my case, i want to bundle the test suite and send to a different team as a jar and execute it in their premises, so i would need this parallel execution and cucmber reporting to work when i package my test suite, but not running using karate.jar, i am using a main class in my project as i mentioned in my first request, https://github.com/ali-nutmeg/broken-karate like here. Is it possible to achieve parallel execution and cucumber reporting in this scenario